# Set default view for all salesforce system administrator of an org

Tags: profile, view, system-admin

How can I set default view for all salesforce system administrator of an org ?
I need to find same tabs when login with different user's having system admin profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an APP for user. Add all the tabs in it and make it default for System admin profile.

[Build Your Own Salesforce App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=dev_tabsets.htm&type=5)